# Replacing method for words with boundaries in python (like with regex)

Tags: python, regex, replace, nlp

I am seeking for  a more robust replace method in python because I am building a 
spellchecker to input words in ocr-context.

Let's say we have the following text in python:

```
text =  """
this is a text, generated using optical character recognition. 
this ls having a lot of errors because
the scanned pdf has too bad resolution.
Unfortunately, his text is very difficult to work with. 
"""
```

It is easy to realize that instead of "his is a text" the right phrase would be "this is a text".
And if I do text.replace('his','this') then I replace every single 'his' for this, so I would get errors like "tthis" is a text.
When I do a replacement. I would like to replace the whole word 'this' and not his or this.
Why not trying this?

```
word_to_replace='his'
corrected_word = 'this'
corrected_text = re.sub('\b'+word_to_replace+'\b',corrected_word,text)
corrected_text
```

Awesome, we did it, but the problem is... what if the word to correct contains an special character like '|'. For example,
'|ights are on' instead of 'lights are one'. Trust me, it happened to me, the re.sub is a disaster in that case. 
The question is, have you encountered the same problem? Is there any method to solve this? The replacement is the most
robust option. 
I tried text.replace(' '+word_to_replace+' ',' '+word_to_replace+' ') and this solve a lot of things but still 
have the problem of phrases like "his is a text " because the replacement doesnt work here since 'his' is at the begining of a sentence
and not ' his ' for ' this '.

Is there any replacement method in python that takes the whole word like in regexs \b word_to_correct \b 
as input ?

Comment: I don't think there's a simple function that just solves what you're talking about. OCR normalization is a HUGE field! However, I do recommend looking into https://pypi.org/project/symspellpy/, which can do a lot with OCR issues.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, I will take a look to that library.

Comment: No need for thanks, but please vote for my response if it helps you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after a few days I solved the problem that I had. I hope this could 
be helpful for someone else. Let me know if you have any question or something.

```
text =  """
this is a text, generated using optical character recognition. 
this ls having a lot of errors because
the scanned pdf has too bad resolution.
Unfortunately, his text is very difficult to work with. 
"""


# Asume you already have corrected your word via ocr 
# and you just have to replace it in the text (I did it with my ocr spellchecker)
# So we get the following word2correct and corrected_word (word after spellchecking system)
word2correct = 'his'
corrected_word = 'this'

#
# now we replace the word and the its context
def context_replace(old_word,new_word,text):
    # Match word between boundaries \\b\ using regex. This will capture his and its context but not this  and its context
    phrase2correct = re.findall('.{1,10}'+'\\b'+word2correct+'\\b'+'.{1,10}',text)[0]
    # Once you matched the context, input the new word 
    phrase_corrected = phrase2correct.replace(word2correct,corrected_word)
    # Now replace  the old phrase (phrase2correct) with the new one *phrase_corrected
    text = text.replace(phrase2correct,phrase_corrected)
    return text
```

Test if the function works...

```
print(context_replace(old_word=word2correct,new_word=corrected_word,text=text))
```

Output:

```
this is a text, generated using optical character recognition. 
this ls having a lot of errors because
the scanned pdf has too bad resolution.
Unfortunately, this text is very difficult to work with.
```

It worked for my purpose. I hope this is helpful for someone else.